# Undefined operation: "500px gte medium-screens"

Tags: sass

I'm trying to combine Jake Archibald's mobile-friendly IE sass mixins... http://jakearchibald.github.io/sass-ie ...with the responsive mixins illustrated by Dan Cederholm in his book 'Sass for Web Designers'.  I'm using CodeKit to compile the files (detailed below).

all.scss compiles successfully, but all-old-ie.scss fails.  CodeKit says:

> Error: Undefined operation: "500px gte medium-screens".
>
> on line 8 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sass-ie-test/sass/_utils.scss, in `responsive'
>
> from line 4 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sass-ie-test/sass/_layout.scss
>
> from line 2 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sass-ie-test/sass/all.scss
>
> from line 3 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sass-ie-test/sass/all-old-ie.scss
>
> Use --trace for backtrace.

Not sure what's going on here.  My files are:

**_utils.scss**

```
$medium: 600px;
$large: 950px;

$fix-mqs: false !default;

@mixin responsive($width) {
    @if $fix-mqs {
        @if $fix-mqs >= $width {
            @content;
        }
    }
    @else if $width == medium-screens {
        @media only screen and (min-width: $medium) { 
            @content;
        }
    }
    @else if $width == large-screens {
        @media only screen and (min-width: $large) { 
            @content;
        }
    }
}

$old-ie: false !default;

@mixin old-ie {
    @if $old-ie {
        @content;
    }
}
```

**_layout.scss**

```
article {
    padding: 30px;

    @include responsive(medium-screens) {
        padding: 50px;
    }

    @include responsive(large-screens) {
        padding: 70px;
    }

    @include old-ie {
        //stuff for ie
    }
}
```

**all.scss**

```
@import 'utils';
@import 'layout';
```

**all-old-ie.scss**

```
$old-ie: true;
$fix-mqs: 500px;
@import 'all';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite clear here.  It explicitly states that it cannot possibly determine whether or not the number `500px` is greater than or equal (`gte`) to the string `medium-screens`.

You're trying to overcomplicate things for no reason: just use variables.

```
$medium: 600px;
$large: 950px;

@mixin responsive($width) {
    @if $fix-mqs {
        @if $fix-mqs >= $width {
            @content;
        }
    } @else {
        @media only screen and (min-width: $width) { 
            @content;
        }
    }
}

article {
    padding: 30px;

    @include responsive($medium) {
        padding: 50px;
    }

    @include responsive($large) {
        padding: 70px;
    }

    @include old-ie {
        //stuff for ie
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it, thanks.  Very helpful.  But how would this work if I wanted to use both a min-width and max-width in a single media query?  For example: `@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) and (max-width : 679px)` Is there a way to integrate that into your suggestion?  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Then that's a lot more work...  There's a few ways you could do it, and there's probably a few libraries out in the wild that already do the job.  [I wrote such a mixin a long long time ago](https://github.com/cimmanon/gmedia), back before mappings were added.  It's not great, but it would at least give you some ideas.